# using machinectl as a container manager on a LAN

Tags: dhcp, iproute, systemd-nspawn

I have a variety of containers that I would like to spin up on a host, and have them immediately get an IP from my DHCP server, just as my bare metal devices do (phone, laptop, NAS, etc)

I would like to be able to destroy these containers at will without a lot of cruft (bridges, VLANS, etc) leftover on my host system.

what are some simple `spinup.sh` and `teardown.sh` commands I could use in that workflow? Or maybe everything could be neatly contained in `/etc/systemd/nspawn/container-x.nspawn`?

Note: I am specifically looking for a *non-docker* solution. Something that is only reliant on systemd

Comment: do you have the networking sorted already?  I'm not sure how you get from "container" which is "just" a namespaced process and isolated filesystem, to dhcp lease from the physical network, without assigning each docker container a unique MAC address on that physical network, which I can't think of how to do either

Comment: no. networking is not sorted already. It's the machinectl and systemd-nspawn layers that offer ways to provide networking by connecting to the host system. Exactly how, is the essence of my question

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/ this might be said cruft

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion. I meant containers in the more general, non-docker way. I mean images that live in `/var/lib/machines`. I'm looking for the nspawn equivilant of docker networking

Answer (score 1):

The networking is actually surprisingly easy. By default (at least with the versions that I've used), the container will use the host's network interfaces. There are many ways of doing this, but the following recipe to set up a container to run a VNC client using `systemd-nspawn` (on a console only host) should provide a good basis for further experimentation:-

The host will need the following packages to be installed: `debootstrap`, `systemd-container`, `sway`, `xwayland` (`xwayland` is only required because `tigervnc-viewer` is not a native Wayland app).

To create the container:

```
debootstrap --force-check-gpg --include=systemd-container,dbus,tigervnc-viewer bookworm /var/lib/machines/vncviewer/ https://deb.debian.org/debian
```

Then set up the container. Get a root prompt with:

```
systemd-nspawn -D /var/lib/machines/vncviewer/
```

Then add a non-root user (e.g. 'theuser'):

```
adduser theuser
```

Finally, enable basic networking in the container, and exit it:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd
exit
```

Some config for the container is required. Create the file `/etc/systemd/nspawn/vncviewer.nspawn` with this content :

```
[Exec]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
```

To run the container:

```
systemd-nspawn -D /var/lib/machines/vncviewer/ --user=theuser vncviewer <IP address of a VNC server>
```

To stop it, you can either kill the `systemd-nspawn` process, or (IIRC) `machinectl poweroff vncviewer`

To completely remove it, you can just delete `/var/lib/machines/vncviewer` and `/etc/systemd/nspawn/vncviewer.nspawn`.